flutterfire configure does not work after correct installation
I have tried to implement firebase for authentication purposes in my flutter project.
I have followed the docs and installed the CLI, added the PATH environment variable, logged via 'firebase login'.
When I try to run 'flutterfire configure' via vscode terminal in my project directory I get following error:

FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.

I have active 1 project, which I've created via firebase console on my web browser. The error says 0 projects.
I've tried to 'firebase logout' then 'firebase login' to renew my token but I did not help.
Also, I have rerun the CLI installer, but it detects that CLI is already installed and that im logged in.
Adding the flutterfire.exe to the project root folder also did not solve the issue.
After adding the env variable I also had to add:
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32;" to the system env variables since I was getting an github error - "Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.", but I do not know if that is relevant to the main firebase error.
